# How to get the last item of an array and delete it from the array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

I need to get the last one and then delete it from an array called `arr`:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: This question was asked by another user, who then deleted it.  Since they don't want it associated with their own account, I re-posted it so the answer is preserved.  I made the question CW so I don't gain reputation from it.  This is the fairest solution I could think of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to do exactly what the [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/pop) method does:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
//...
var last = arr.pop(); // returns 4, and arr will contain now [1, 2, 3]
```